# how can I add sum rows in django import-export library?

Tags: django, django-import-export

How can I add sum row on the bottom of my table in exported xlsx file?

I don't see anything like that in their doc but maybe you did something similar. I'd like to summarize only the `total_price` column.

My resource looks like this:

```
class CERequestResource(resources.ModelResource):

    related_component__service = Field(attribute='related_component__service')
    related_product__title = Field(attribute='related_product__title'')
    related_component__component_name = Field(attribute='related_component__component_name')
    related_component__task_description = Field(attribute='related_component__task_description')
    related_component__position = Field(attribute='related_component__position')
    number_of_units = Field(attribute='number_of_units', column_name='# of Units')
    related_component__margin = Field(attribute='related_component__margin')
    total_price = Field(attribute="total_price")
    
    model = CERequest
    fields = ('id', 'related_component', 'related_product', 'number_of_units', 'total_price', 'margin')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really easy - override one method like so:

```py
    def after_export(self, queryset, data, *args, **kwargs):
        total = 0
        for row in data.dict:
            total += Decimal(row["total_price"])
        # this list must equal the width of your row
        # with the total appearing at the same position as
        # 'total_price'
        data.append(["", "", "", "", total, ""])
```

Note that your example is declared wrong.  `fields` and `model` need to be under the `Meta` class declaration:

```py
    class Meta: 
        model = CERequest
        fields = ('id', 'related_component', 'related_product', 'number_of_units', 'total_price', 'margin')
```